# How to close unclosed HTML Tags?

Tags: javascript, php

Whenever we are fetching some user inputed content with some editing from the database or similar sources, we might retrieve the portion which only contains the opening tag but no closing.

This can hamper the website's current layout.

Is there a clientside or serverside way of fixing this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found a great answer for this one:

Use PHP 5 and use the loadHTML() method of the DOMDocument object. This auto parses badly formed HTML and a subsequent call to saveXML() will output the valid HTML. The DOM functions can be found here:

http://www.php.net/dom

The usage of this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($yourText);
$yourText = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Improving for XHTML: `$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html_tags>'.$html_text.'</html_tags>');
libxml_clear_errors();
$html_text = substr($doc->saveXML($doc->getElementsByTagName('html_tags')->item(0)), strlen('<html_tags>'), -strlen('</html_tags>'));`

Comment: Shame there's no `$doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->innerHTML()`   method, but [in the comments here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#101243) there are at least three wacky ways to do it.

Comment: Its nice to use standard PHP libraries, but its a bit messy that this technique doesn't work with HTML fragments without doing a selector at the end of it all .

Comment: To use this inline (no `!DOCTYPE` and no `<html><body>` tags), I used this: `$inner = substr($yourText, 119, strlen($yourText) - 119 - 15);` The 119 characters are for the doctype and opening tags; the 15 are for the closing tags and the final newline. Not as neat as parsing the DOM and taking the inner stuff, but it's shorter, easier and probably a lot quicker too.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone See my answer, there is a fairly succinct way of doing it.. as saveHTML() can take a DOMNode.

Comment: Would this also fix incomplete table rows (given 1 or more rows are provided before the point the html is broken)?

Answer (score 16):

I have solution for php

```
<?php
    // close opened html tags
    function closetags ( $html )
        {
        #put all opened tags into an array
        preg_match_all ( "#<([a-z]+)( .*)?(?!/)>#iU", $html, $result );
        $openedtags = $result[1];

        #put all closed tags into an array
        preg_match_all ( "#</([a-z]+)>#iU", $html, $result );
        $closedtags = $result[1];
        $len_opened = count ( $openedtags );

        # all tags are closed
        if( count ( $closedtags ) == $len_opened )
        {
            return $html;
        }
        $openedtags = array_reverse ( $openedtags );

        # close tags
        for( $i = 0; $i < $len_opened; $i++ )
        {
            if ( !in_array ( $openedtags[$i], $closedtags ) )
            {
                $html .= "</" . $openedtags[$i] . ">";
            }
            else
            {
                unset ( $closedtags[array_search ( $openedtags[$i], $closedtags)] );
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }
    // close opened html tags
?>
```

You can use this function like

```
   <?php echo closetags("your content <p>test test"); ?>
```

Comment: I like that function. One problem I see is that it can't fix broken nesting (e.g. `"<b>Bold and <i>Italic</b> text"`), which some users are so skilled at doing.

Comment: -1 checking `count($closedtags) == count($openedtags)` is not enough ... e.g. `"<a href=''><b>link</a></a>"`

Answer (score 15):

You can use [Tidy](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/intro.tidy.php):

> Tidy is a binding for the Tidy HTML clean and repair utility which allows you to not only clean and otherwise manipulate HTML documents, but also traverse the document tree.

or [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant 
>     HTML filter library written in 
>     PHP. HTML Purifier will not only remove all malicious 
>     code (better known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited, 
>     secure yet permissive whitelist,
>     it will also make sure your documents are 
>     standards compliant, something only achievable with a 
>     comprehensive knowledge of W3C's specifications.

Answer (score 8):

For HTML fragments, and working from [KJS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10988758/1051628) I have had success with the following when the fragment has one root element:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$body = $dom->documentElement->firstChild->firstChild;
$string = $dom->saveHTML($body);
```

Without a root element this is possible (but seems to wrap only the first text child node in p tags in `text <p>para</p> text`):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$bodyChildNodes = $dom->documentElement->firstChild->childNodes;

$string = '';
foreach ($bodyChildNodes as $node){
   $string .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
```

Or better yet, from PHP >= 5.4 and libxml >= 2.7.8 (2.7.7 for `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED`):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

// Load with no html/body tags and do not add a default dtd
$dom->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$string = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This comment helped me out a ton. Just needed to add these two elements to your code:

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);  // before you declare new DOMDoc to suppress errors.

Account for special characters using mb_convert_encoding() here: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#74777

Comment: I've just +1ed this because of the section for LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED etc, which sorted out my problems with fragments perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to server-side tools like Tidy, you can also use the user's browser to do some of the cleanup for you. One of the really great things about `innerHTML` is that it will apply the same on-the-fly repair to dynamic content as it does to HTML pages. This code works pretty well (with two caveats) and nothing actually gets written to the page:

```
var divTemp = document.createElement('div');
divTemp.innerHTML = '<p id="myPara">these <i>tags aren\'t <strong> closed';
console.log(divTemp.innerHTML);
```

The caveats:

1. The different browsers will return different strings. This isn't so bad, except in the the case of IE, which will return capitalized tags and will strip the quotes from tag attributes, which will not pass validation. The solution here is to do some simple clean-up on the server side. But at least the document will be properly structured XML.
2. I suspect that you may have to put in a delay before reading the innerHTML -- give the browser a chance to digest the string -- or you risk getting back exactly what was put in. I just tried on IE8 and it looks like the string gets parsed immediately, but I'm not so sure on IE6. It would probably be best to read the innerHTML after a delay (or throw it into a setTimeout() to force it to the end of the queue).

I would recommend you take @Gordon's advice and use Tidy if you have access to it (it takes less work to implement) and failing that, use innerHTML and write your own tidy function in PHP.

And though this isn't part of your question, as this is for a CMS, consider also using the [YUI 2 Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) for stuff like this. It's fairly easy to implement, somewhat easy to customize, the interface is very familiar to most users, and it spits out perfectly valid code. There are several other off-the-shelf rich text editors out there, but YUI has the best license and is the most powerful I've seen.

Answer (score 3):

A better PHP function to delete not open/not closed tags from webmaster-glossar.de (me)

```
function closetag($html){
    $html_new = $html;
    preg_match_all ( "#<([a-z]+)( .*)?(?!/)>#iU", $html, $result1);
    preg_match_all ( "#</([a-z]+)>#iU", $html, $result2);
    $results_start = $result1[1];
    $results_end = $result2[1];
    foreach($results_start AS $startag){
        if(!in_array($startag, $results_end)){
            $html_new = str_replace('<'.$startag.'>', '', $html_new);
        }
    }
    foreach($results_end AS $endtag){
        if(!in_array($endtag, $results_start)){
            $html_new = str_replace('</'.$endtag.'>', '', $html_new);
        }
    }
    return $html_new;
}
```

use this function like:

```
closetag('i <b>love</b> my <strike>cat'); 
#output: i <b>love</b> my cat

closetag('i <b>love</b> my cat</strike>'); 
#output: i <b>love</b> my cat
```

Comment: works only when the unclosed tag is different then before echo closetag('i <b>love</b> my cat...</b>'); will not work

Answer (score 0):

Erik Arvidsson wrote a nice HTML SAX parser in 2004. http://erik.eae.net/archives/2004/11/20/12.18.31/

It keeps track of the the open tags, so with a minimalistic SAX handler it's possible to insert closing tags at the correct position:

```
function tidyHTML(html) {
    var output = '';
    HTMLParser(html, {
        comment: function(text) {
            // filter html comments
        },
        chars: function(text) {
            output += text;
        },
        start: function(tagName, attrs, unary) {
            output += '<' + tagName;
            for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
                output += ' ' + attrs[i].name + '=';
                if (attrs[i].value.indexOf('"') === -1) {
                    output += '"' + attrs[i].value + '"';
                } else if (attrs[i].value.indexOf('\'') === -1) {
                    output += '\'' + attrs[i].value + '\'';
                } else { // value contains " and ' so it cannot contain spaces
                    output += attrs[i].value;
                }
            }
            output += '>';
        },
        end: function(tagName) {
            output += '</' + tagName + '>';
        }
    });
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to the native DOMDocument method, but with a few improvements for safety.

Note, other answers that use DOMDocument do not consider html strands such as

```
This is a <em>HTML</em> strand
```

The above will actually result in

```
<p>This is a <em>HTML</em> strand
```

My Solution is below

```
function closeDanglingTags($html) {
    if (strpos($html, '<') || strpos($html, '>')) {
        // There are definitiley HTML tags
        $wrapped = false;
        if (strpos(trim($html), '<') !== 0) {
            // The HTML starts with a text node. Wrap it in an element with an id to prevent the software wrapping it with a <p>
            //  that we know nothing about and cannot safely retrieve
            $html = cHE::getDivHtml($html, null, 'closedanglingtagswrapper');
            $wrapped = true;
        }
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->encoding = 'utf-8';
        @$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        if ($doc->firstChild) {
            // Test whether the firstchild is definitely a DOMDocumentType
            if ($doc->firstChild instanceof DOMDocumentType) {
                // Remove the added doctype
                $doc->removeChild($doc->firstChild);
            }
        }
        if ($wrapped) {
            // The contents originally started with a text node and was wrapped in a div#plasmappclibtextwrap. Take the contents
            //  out of that div
            $node = $doc->getElementById('closedanglingtagswrapper');
            $children = $node->childNodes;  // The contents of the div. Equivalent to $('selector').children()
            $doc = new DOMDocument();   // Create a new document to add the contents to, equiv. to "var doc = $('<html></html>');"
            foreach ($children as $childnode) {
                $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($childnode, true)); // E.g. doc.append()
            }
        }
        // Remove the added html,body tags
        return trim(str_replace(array('<html><body>', '</body></html>'), '', html_entity_decode($doc->saveHTML())));
    } else {
        return $html;
    }
}
```