# CodeIgniter word_wrap and I code

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, word-wrap

So, I have this problem that when I word_wrap the text field. But when I word_wrapped, it didn't get the `</i>` so, it ended up with whole website got italic text.

```
<?php echo word_limiter($news_item['text'], 10); ?>
```

How do I fix that?

... Now i just realized that every tag HTML (i begin, but not end) I do, does still work? I just use the XSS fixer... Shouldn't it fix this as well? And more importantly how do I fix this, but I still want to allow clean HTML. (But they have to close the tag!!!!)

```
> <John13> Hello [14:13] <John13> When I use the xss clean (function) It
> doesn't prevent tags that ain't closed. How do I fix it? [14:14]
> <John13> For example <b>blablabla.... (end of post) Now all rest of
> text will be bold on the site.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) - "strip_tags — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string"

So try this

```
<?php echo word_limiter(strip_tags($news_item['text']), 10); ?>
```

**EDIT:**
[How to close unclosed HTML Tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059398/how-to-close-unclosed-html-tags)

Comment: The thing is I still want to make HTML available (as XSS cleaning function just remove bad code) But.. when someone starts for example a bold tag, and dont end it all will get bold, I don't want that. That's the fix Im looking for.

Comment: So you want 10 words to be still bold or italic or a link? Uf, i'm clueless there

Comment: No, it's not just there. Look. if someone types the bold tag, but doesn't end it.. It will be bold over the whole page. That's not what Im looking for hehe :)

Comment: If i get you correct: This **is** an example _how_ text should be like, without screwing". Where if there was bold before "screwing" it would be closed. Correct? Look at edit