# How to free a paragraph from its CSS style?

Tags: php, css, strlen

I am using [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) as rich text editor for my website. And after i edit the text, it is stored in my database.

Say I have edited some text and it is stored like this in the content field:

```
<div> This is just some sample <b>text that is displayed </b> to help <a href="#"> My example </a> </div>
```

Now when i want to display some portion of the content in my home page and add a "Read more" link so users can reach to the actual page.

```
<?php
     echo substr($row['content'],0,50);
     if(strlen($row['content']))>50 ) {
       echo "<a href=\"#\"> read more </a>";
     }
?>
```

So the above code will extract say:

```
<div> This is just some sample <b>text
```

from the content field of the table. And when it is displayed on the page, we can see that neither the `<div>` is closed nor the `<b>`. So the rest of the content in the page is completly messed up.

What can be a solution?

Comment: You can't just chop off the end of an HTML snippet - you'll break the whole DOM structure if there's any 'open' tags straddling the cut point. You need to use DOM operations to rebuild the string and eliminate the text-but-not-tags which extends past the cut point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close unclosed HTMl Tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059398/how-to-close-unclosed-html-tags)

Comment: I think you have one to many ) in your statement. if(strlen($row['content'])>50) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo substr(strip_tags($row['content']),0,50)`

Then when they 'get more' do not run `strip_tags()`

Updated..

Comment: No problem, maybe mark as answer if you are using it as your solution.

Comment: Now there is another problem. It is striping the tags but adding empty space in its place. So while displaying .. it shows like nothing.. or very few chars even if i have used substr($data,0,250)

Comment: Try this: `echo substr(strip_tags($row['content']),0,50)`

Comment: I used `substr(trim(strip_tags($row['content'])),0,50)` and it worked fine.. removed the tags.. removed the white spaces in the begining and displayed it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method — just show summary text as «plain text» using `strip_tags()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at php's strip_tags() function: 
http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of `strip_tags` as there is no easy way to close tags automatically. You can however, take a look at this question: [How to close unclosed HTML Tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059398/how-to-close-unclosed-html-tags)

Comment: Now there is another problem.
It is striping the tags but adding empty space in its place. So while displaying .. it shows like nothing.. or very few chars even if i have used substr($data,0,250)