# Javascript : Close open HTML tags in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript string that has HTML code. I display it and I have attached a read more/less toggler based on the number of words. The problem is, when I shrink the HTML code, it might have open tags, for suppose

```
<p>A computer is a general purpose device that can be <b>programmed</b> to carry out a finite set of arithmetic or logical operations</p>
```

when shrinked becomes

```
<p>A computer is a general purpose device that can be <b>programmed...more</p>
```

Because of unclosed bold tag, the following data becomes bold.

I want a javascript solution to close the unclosed tags in a string. Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: show everything as a string? Server won't process any code or tag and display as string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close unclosed HTMl Tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059398/how-to-close-unclosed-html-tags)

Comment: Before shrinking it find out the number of tags (ie p, br, b etc) that you have. Now you know how many tags there are . If you have 1 p and 1 br tag , then totally you have 4 tags including the closing tags as well. After shrinking find out if you have the same no of tags.If not append the absent tags at the appropriate positions .

Comment: One approach would be to load the string in a DOM node (e.g. a hidden div) and manipulate only _text nodes_ inside that node, leaving other nodes (tags) intact.

Comment: You can also avoid cutting text and just hide it with CSS using `max-height` and `overflow:hidden` for example.

Comment: @TheBronx except then you may end up with partial lines of text visible at the bottom cutoff point.

Answer (score 22):

Use this code

```
function fixHtml(html){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML=html
  return (div.innerHTML);
}
```

using

```
var fixed = fixHtml("<b>some text")
```

will return

```
 <b>some text</b>
```

Comment: Ah, that saves a lot of time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The "...more" should not even be in the paragraph. Try adding it separately, out of the paragraph.

You might want to wrap everything in a `div` instead, and shrink that.

```
<div class="shrinkable">

    <p>A computer is a general purpose device that can be <b>programmed</b> to carry out a finite set of arithmetic or logical operations</p>
    <span class="see-more">...more</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and used the following solution. I adjusted it to your example.

```
var divContent = document.createElement('div');
```

get the html from the div you want to shrink

```
var get_html = $('.shrinkable').html();
```

use innerHTML, this takes care of any open tags in the html

```
divContent.innerHTML = get_html;
```

replace the html and add the see

```
$('.shrinkable').html(divContent.innerHTML).append('<span class="see-more">...more</span>');
```