# Can I build opening/closing tags while iterating over a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that has some html tags in it. I want to be able to find an opening and closing tag, and add those that are missing.
For example, lets say I have this string:

```
Hello <strong>from <em>StackOverflow</strong> Hows it going</em>.
```

I want to be able to close the first `<em>` before the closing `</strong>` and add an opening `<em>` right after the closing `</strong>`. 
I will know what tags are included, but the stringI am provided could contain any variation of mixed up opening/closing tags.

How could I handle this without help from DOMParser or innerHTML?

Basically, I want to iterate the string and when I come across `<`, I want to start an opening string, and close it at `>`. Then, I want to start a closing tag when I come across `</` and end it at `>`.

The problem is, when iterating a string, I will always start an opening tag due to checking one char at a time? How can I build these tags out of my string as I iterate?

Comment: Please read the [canonical/obligatory answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1715579) before going down this path.

Comment: Got it, updating the question now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : Close open HTML tags in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749078/javascript-close-open-html-tags-in-a-string)

Comment: This is not a dupe of that question. That questions answer uses innerHTML. I want to do this without the help of DOMParser or the browser. Before anyone mentions that Javascript requires a browser, please consider it server side Javascript for the sake of this argument.

Comment: Use a library such as htmltidy.

Comment: Server-side JS can use DOM libraries.

Comment: @torazaburo I know it can use DOM libraries, I am trying to write this myself, without the help of libraries.

Comment: Downvoter of the question, can you please explain why you feel this way? It is not a duplicate.

Comment: It's a one-year project to write something which reliably tidies up HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could find where both the opening and closing tags **are** in JavaScript with a regex like `(<.+?>)`, but considering regex lookbehind is unsupported in JavaScript, what you are asking is probably impossible, due to the fact that you'll never be able to work out which end tag correlates to which start tag.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, my thinking was to push the tag to a stack. Then I can check the tag type, `strong` etc. If I am pushing a closing tag onto its corresponding opening tag, then I can just pop the opening and move on, as that is not incorrect html. If however, I am pushing a closing `</i>` onto an open `<strong>`, then I know I need to add a closing `</strong>` to the string at that index. Is that a crazy thought?

Comment: The problem with that is that nested tags can have the **same** type. For example, you can have a div within a div. You may find [the comments here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823200/final-solution-for-using-regex-to-remove-html-nested-tags-of-the-same-type) helpful in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that without the tags being closed properly there is no logic to figure out when they should be closed.

You can loop through strings in Javascript the same way you can loop through arrays.

```
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    var character = string[i];
    //add more loops here to look through subsequent characters for patterns...
}
```

Please note that this will have to be done on the string BEFORE it is output to the page because modern browsers will automatically close off opened tags that are missing a closing tab at the following position.

However, looking for patterns and figuring out when to close and open each tag is actually very complex.

I would recommend using a library. Otherwise you will spend 2 months or so re-inventing the wheel.

The example you posted is simple.

```
Hello <strong>from <em>StackOverflow</strong> Hows it going</em>.
```

Should become

```
Hello <strong>from <em>StackOverflow</em></strong><em> Hows it going</em>.
```

But what happens when you have something like

```
Hello <em><strong> </strong>from <em></strong> Stackoverflow ...
```

There are some situations where there is just no way to know where the tags need to be unless you are the content author.

So the best solution would be to eliminate the source of the incorrect tags and make sure that the content creation process doesn't have any of those flaws.

You could also just loop through the string and close off any tags immediately after they are opened if the following closing tag doesn't match the opening tag. This is what Chrome/Firefox etc. will do automatically anyway. That ensures the HTML is staying correct and won't break the page.