# Remove not closed html elements from end of text

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to remove all elements which are not closed properly at the end of content e.g in below test

```
commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea
voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, 
vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla 
pariatur? <a rel="nofollow" class="underline"
```

I want to remove

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="underline"
```

or elements without closing tags

```
<h2>sample text
```

or any other html element which is not closed properly at the end.

Comment: Do you simply want to remove them entirely, or fix them instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059398/how-to-close-unclosed-html-tags

Comment: i just want to remove broken html element from end of text, not all

Comment: @nyzm mentioned url uses plugins, i want to avoid plugins if possible

Comment: you can do this by http://codepad.org/EupocXQR but i dont support that idea

Comment: how will you know it's a tag and not legit content with a <   ?

Comment: @d'alar'cop if not in a pre-tag, it should be written as `&lt;`, no?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit it will depend at which point he wants to do this cleaning exercise I guess

Answer (score 4):

I have written a function that should do what you want. The idea is to first replace all valid tag-sequences with a `####` pattern. Then a regular expression removes everything from the first `<` till the end of the string. After that, the valid tag-sequences are put back to the buffer (if that part has not been removed due to invalid tag before that part).

Too bad, I can't add a codepad because recursive regular expressions seems not to be supported by the PHP version used by codepad. I've tested this with PHP 5.3.5.

**PHP**

```
function StripUnclosedTags($input) {
    // Close <br> tags
    $buffer = str_ireplace("<br>", "<br/>", $input);
    // Find all matching open/close HTML tags (using recursion)
    $pattern = "/<([\w]+)([^>]*?) (([\s]*\/>)| (>((([^<]*?|<\!\-\-.*?\-\->)| (?R))*)<\/\\1[\s]*>))/ixsm";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $buffer, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    // Mask matching open/close tag sequences in the buffer
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $ofs = $match[1];
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($match[0]); $i++, $ofs++)
            $buffer[$ofs] = "#";
    }
    // Remove unclosed tags
    $buffer = preg_replace("/<.*$/", "", $buffer);
    // Put back content of matching open/close tag sequences to the buffer
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $ofs = $match[1];
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($match[0]) && $ofs < strlen($buffer); $i++, $ofs++)
            $buffer[$ofs] = $match[0][$i];
    }
    return $buffer;
}

$str = 'commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate '
      .'velit esse<br> quam nihil molestiae consequatur,  vel illum qui dolorem eum '
      .'fugiat quo voluptas nulla  pariatur? '
      .'<a href="test">test<p></p></a><span>test<p></p>bla';

var_dump(StripUnclosedTags($str));
```

**Output**

```
string 'commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea
voluptate velit esse<br/> quam nihil molestiae consequatur, 
vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla 
pariatur? <a href="test">test<p></p></a>' (length=226)
```