# How to strip characters from a php string without disturbing HTML tags

Tags: php, html

I have a string containing html tags as follows.

`$desc = "<p>Lorem <strong>ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet</p><p>Duo at agam maiorum instructior, ut tale quidam ancillae qui, est cu paulo consetetur.</p>"`

I want to take first 10 characters such that:

1. HTML Tags are not part of the counting.
2. All the HTML Tags which were opened are properly closed.

Now if use substr:

```
$result = substr($desc, 0, 10);
```

actual result is: `<p>Lorem <`

what i want is: `<p>Lorem <strong>ipsu</strong></p>`

Comment: you would be better off parsing it with [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: @MattHB will you please tell me how can i do it with DomDocument?

Comment: it would be beyond the scope of SO for me to give you an answer of that detail Im afraid. however if you search the site for `DOMDocument` youll get lots of results that would point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by using a very nice code from here 
[How to close unclosed HTML Tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059398/how-to-close-unclosed-html-tags) answered by kamal

```
<?php
 $str = "<p>Lorem <strong>ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet</p><p>Duo at agam maiorum instructior, ut tale quidam ancillae qui, est cu paulo consetetur.</p>";
 $s = strip_tags($str);
 $result = substr($s, 0, 10);
 $sarr = explode(' ', $result);
 $last = end($sarr);
 $l = strpos($str, $last);
 $r = substr($str, 0, $l);
 echo closetags($r.$last);

 function closetags ( $html )
    {
    #put all opened tags into an array
    preg_match_all ( "#<([a-z]+)( .*)?(?!/)>#iU", $html, $result );
    $openedtags = $result[1];
    #put all closed tags into an array
    preg_match_all ( "#</([a-z]+)>#iU", $html, $result );
    $closedtags = $result[1];
    $len_opened = count ( $openedtags );
    # all tags are closed
    if( count ( $closedtags ) == $len_opened )
    {
    return $html;
    }
    $openedtags = array_reverse ( $openedtags );
    # close tags
    for( $i = 0; $i < $len_opened; $i++ )
    {
        if ( !in_array ( $openedtags[$i], $closedtags ) )
        {
        $html .= "</" . $openedtags[$i] . ">";
        }
        else
        {
        unset ( $closedtags[array_search ( $openedtags[$i], $closedtags)] );
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
?>
```