# str_replace with content not replacing

Tags: php, str-replace

**Hello Stackers,**

I'm just having a small PHP Question about the `str_replace()` Function. When I replace something, it will just replace everything; That's okay. But what I would like to know is this:

```
str_replace("*", "<strong>", $message);
```

Is it possible to use str_replace for codes like * This content is Bold *, just having the content, but still replacing the asterisk's with `<strong>` and `</strong>`?

Example:

Original: `**This Should be Bold**` 
After Replacing: `<strong>This Should be Bold</strong>`

For people flagging this as a Duplicate: It's not about closing HTML Tags, it's about replacing.

I Hope I'm not that unclear. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Not with str_replace, you can do it with [PREG_REPLACE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: There are already libraries that can do that for you, just look for something like `php markdown`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close unclosed HTML Tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059398/how-to-close-unclosed-html-tags)

Comment: use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

Comment: Do you want to write a markdown parser? If so, I recommend to use an existing library instead of writing your own (unless you want to practice how to write and optimize parsers)

Comment: @jeroen that's the most sensible suggestion, I second that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expression instead; it's more convenient:

```
$message = "**This Should be Bold**";
$message = preg_replace('#\**([^\*]+)\**#m', '<strong>$1</strong>', $message);
echo $message;
```

Or if you want to limit the number of asteroids to 2:

```
'#\*{1,2}([^\*]+)\*{1,2}#m'
```

Comment: @Gouda Elalfy why did you change `[^\*]+` to `[^\**]+`?

Comment: to replace 2 * stars

Comment: @GoudaElalfy but inside `[]`? Are you sure?

Comment: If you want to support `**This bold has a * inside**`, maybe you can try doing the replaces one by one.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ edited, thanks. But still, different for those inside `[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this

https://eval.in/518881

```
<?php
    $string = '**This Should be Bold**';
    $string = preg_replace("/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/", "<strong>$1</strong>", $string);
    echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: Will not work with `**This** and **this** are both bold`. The `and` will become bold too,