# How to close unclosed HTML Tags in node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Whenever we are fetching some user inputed content with some editing from the database or similar sources, we might retrieve the portion which only contains the opening tag but no closing.

This can hamper the website's current layout.

Is there a node.js serverside way of fixing this?

This question has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059398/how-to-close-unclosed-html-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1), but it's in PHP.

**Inner HTML solution**
A solution could work, this [innerHTML solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059552/3503352), but it doesn't work for me...
Here is the code:

```
var divTemp = document.createElement("div");
divTemp.innerHTML = html;

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(divTemp.innerHTML);
  $("input[name='" + inputName + "']").val(divTemp.innerHTML);
}, 6000);
```

This is an example of the html I enter:

```
<h2 style="box-sizing: inherit; font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Definition and Usage</h2><p style="box-sizing: inherit; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;">The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.</p><p style="box-sizing: inherit; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;"><b style="box-sizing: inherit;">Tip:</b>&nbsp;1000 ms = 1 second.</p><p style="box-sizing: inherit; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;"><strong style="box-sizing: inherit;">Tip:</strong>&nbsp;The function is only executed once. If you need to repeat execution, use the&nbsp;<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp" style="box-sizing: inherit; color: inherit;">setInterval()</a>&nbsp;method.&nbsp;</p><p style="box-sizing: inherit; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;"><strong style="box-sizing: inherit;">Tip:</strong>&nbsp;Use the&nbsp;<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp" style="box-sizing: inherit; color: inherit;">clearTimeout()</a>&nbsp;method to prevent the function from running.</p><div><br></div>
```

Finally,`divTemp.innerHTML` and `html` are the same.

So, I'm waiting for a solution, or a reason why the inner HTML solution doesn't work.

Thanks a lot !

---

**Answer to cheerio solution from @Marcos Casagrande**

I'm doing this but the problem is still the same...
Here is my code:

```
return {
    title: req.body.name,
    description: cheerio
      .load(
        striptags(
          req.body.type === "campaign"
            ? req.body.campaignDescription
            : req.body.type === "donate"
              ? req.body.donateDescription
              : "",
          [
            "div",
            "strong",
            "b",
            "h1",
            "h2",
            "blockquote",
            "i",
            "u",
            "strike",
            "br",
            "img",
            "pre",
            "p",
            "ol",
            "ul",
            "li",
            "hr",
            "a"
          ]
        ),
        { xmlMode: true }
      )
      .html()
}
```

With this solution, this:

```
<h2 style="padding: 2px 0px 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; line-height: 26px; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: url(&quot;/public/images/v6/maincol_gradient_rule.png&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: left bottom; font-family: &quot;Motiva Sans&quot;, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; background-color: rgb(27, 40, 56);">WE. THE REVOLUTION - NEW GAMEPLAY!</h2><p style="padding: 0px; margin-bottom: 8px; color: rgb(172, 178, 184); font-family: &quot;Motiva Sans&quot;, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(27, 40, 56);">Liberty, Equality, Fraternity...or Death! Are You ready to choose? Your career or your family, your prosperity or their misery? It is easy to judge stranger people but how will you manage to adjudicate upon your dearest?</p><h2 class="bb_tag" style="padding: 2px 0px 0px; margin: 18px 0px 0px; line-height: 26px; font-size: 15px; color: rgb(47, 137, 188); background-image: none; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: left bottom; font-family: &quot;Motiva Sans&quot;, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(27, 40, 56);">See We. The Revolution New Gameplay!</h2>
```

becomes

```
<h2 style="padding: 2px 0px 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; line-height: 26px; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: url(&quot;/public/images/v6/maincol_gradient_rule.png&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: left bottom; font-family: &quot;Motiva Sans&quot;, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; background-color: rgb(27, 40, 56);">WE. THE REVOLUTION - NEW GAMEPLAY!</h2><p style="padding: 0px; margin-bottom: 8px; color: rgb(172, 178, 184); font-family: &quot;Motiva Sans&quot;, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(27, 40, 56);">Liberty, Equality, Fraternity...or Death! Are You ready to choose? Your career or your family, your prosperity or their misery? It is easy to judge stranger people but how will you manage to adjudicate upon your dearest?</p><h2 class="bb_tag" style="padding: 2px 0px 0px; margin: 18px 0px 0px; line-height: 26px; font-size: 15px; color: rgb(47, 137, 188); background-image: none; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: left bottom; font-family: &quot;Motiva Sans&quot;, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(27, 40, 56);">See We. The Revolution New Gameplay!</h2>
```

It still breaks the website layout...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) *"A solution could work, this innerHTML solution, but it doesn't work for me..."* ***How so***, precisely? It does work: [proof](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/ovy2swa6/). If you mean it doesn't work because you're using Node.js, there are multiple HTML parsers for Node.js.

Comment: Can you give some sample data that the users gave?

Comment: Thanks for adding code.  However, we still need some more information: "but it doesn't work for me... " is not very descriptive.  Please specify exactly how what is doing differs from what you want it to do, or describe why it does not work for you, or if it throws an error, specify that error.  This information will allow us to quickly and efficiently hone in on the error.  Also without knowing exactly what you want, or exactly why that solution does not work for you how are we to provide a different idea that is any closer to what you desire.

Comment: @SherylHohman The reason why it's not working for me is explained the line below. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that using `cheerio`.

Given the following broken HTML:

```
<div>Name<span>Hey</span>
```

You can get:

```
<div>Name<span>Hey</span></div>
```

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const brokenHtml = '<div>Name<span>Hey</span>';

const $ = cheerio.load(brokenHtml, { xmlMode: true });

console.log($.html()); // <div>Name<span>Hey</span></div>
```

If you don't use: `xmlMode: true`, you will get this instead, which might work for you:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <div>Name<span>Hey</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I've asked. And it's the closest answer to the solution. 
I've tested it and writed feedbacks in my edited question ! :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're saying the `innerHTML` solution doesn't work for you because you're using Node.js and so you don't have a DOM, there are multiple DOM parsers for Node.js. For instance, using [`jsdom`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom):

```
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const str = "<div><span><em>foo";
const dom = new JSDOM(str);
console.log("Before:", str);
console.log("After:", dom.window.document.body.innerHTML);
```

Output:

```
Before: <div><span><em>foo
After: <div><span><em>foo</em></span></div>
```